# calculating the number of blank rows in list of dataframes

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the number of blank rows from list of dataframes.so i am getting a list of dataframes from another function.

now i want to calclate the number of blank rows in df1,df2,df2

```
library(expss)     
df <- mtcars 

df$vs<-factor(df$vs, levels=c(1,0), labels = c("version","others")) 
df$am<-factor(df$am, levels=c(1,0), labels = c("AMP","others"))
df$gear<-factor(df$gear, levels=c(3,4,5), labels = c("3G","4G","5G"))
df$carb<-factor(df$carb, levels=c(1,2,3,4,6,8), labels = c("one","two","three","four","six","eight"))



df$all<- 1 
df$vs1<-ifelse(df$vs=='version',1,NA) 
df$am1<-ifelse(df$am == 'AMP', 1, NA) 
df$gear1<-ifelse(df$gear == '4G', 1, NA)
df$carb1<-ifelse(df$carb == 'three', 1, NA)


expss::val_lab(df$all)<-c("All"=1) 
expss::val_lab(df$vs1)<-c("version"=1) 
expss::val_lab(df$am1)<-c("AMP"=1)
expss::val_lab(df$gear1)<-c("Gear Type"=1)
expss::val_lab(df$am1)<-c("carb type"=1)



df1 <- df %>% filter(all==1)
df2 <- df %>% filter(gear=="4G")
df3 <- df %>% filter(am=="others")

dfs <- list(df1,df2,df3)
varlist <- c("vs1","am1","gear1")

no_data <- sum(rowSums(is.na(df1[varlist]))==length(varlist))
```

the output should be look like
12,0,12

Comment: `sapply(dfs, function(z) sum(rowSums(is.na(z[varlist])) == length(varlist)))`